# How to install libGL on mac os x?

Tags: macos, opengl

I have OS X lion and got this error while building a program that needs GL.

> ld: library not found for -lGL

How can I install libGL? I usually use MacPorts but couldn't find libGL there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use frameworks instead.

```
-framework OpenGL
```

Try that.

Comment: Compiler flags or linker flags.

Comment: Is this the first sign of Apple deprecating OpenGL for real?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cmake, you may use this in your code:

```
    find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

    if (OPENGL_FOUND)
        message("Found OpenGL for Mac OS")
        message("OpenGL for Mac OS, include dir: ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
        message("OpenGL for Mac OS, link libraries: ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}")
    else (OPENGL_FOUND)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "OpenGL for Mac OS not found")
    endif()

    target_link_libraries(${MY_OTHER_LIBS}
        ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}
        ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY}
    )
```

Cheers!